# Memory alignment requirement for data transfer with Direct I/O

Tags: c, linux, malloc, glibc

I am current reading The Linux Programming Interface by Michael Kerrisk. I was going through the [example](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/filebuff/direct_read.c.html) in which memalign() is used for the alignment requirements.

The code and the comment does not make sense to me. Can anyone explain why we require 2 * alignment here ?

```
/* memalign() allocates a block of memory aligned on an address that
       is a multiple of its first argument. By specifying this argument as
       2 * 'alignment' and then adding 'alignment' to the returned pointer,
       we ensure that 'buf' is aligned on a non-power-of-two multiple of
       'alignment'. We do this to ensure that if, for example, we ask
       for a 256-byte aligned buffer, we don't accidentally get
       a buffer that is also aligned on a 512-byte boundary. */

    buf = memalign(alignment * 2, length + alignment);
    if (buf == NULL)
        errExit("memalign");

    buf += alignment;
```

Answer (score 2):

The author here wants a buffer that has n-byte alignment but not 2n-byte alignment, presumably to demonstrate failures due to insufficient alignment or something like that (I don't have the book).

He achieves this by asking for a buffer with 2n-byte alignment (which obviously also has n-byte alignment) and then adding n. This breaks the 2n-byte aligment, but keeps the n-byte alignment.